# Python code doesn't execute on first run

Tags: python

Using Spyder Python 3.6 this code does not execute, says that the method ispal is not defined. However when I run it and put in an integer first (say my string input = 0), then it will run after and recognize the method. It seems like I have to go through a branch other than the call to the method first. Thanks for the critique.

```
s = input('enter a string: ')
s1 = s
s1 = s1.lower()
s1 = s1.replace(',', '')
s1 = s1.replace(' ', '')

if s1.isalpha():
    if ispal(s1) == True:
        print(s,' is a palindrome')
    else:
        print(s,' is not a palindrome')
else:
    print('you entered illegal chars')


def ispal(s1):
    if len(s1) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        #if the first and last char are the same
        #and if all 
       return s1[0] == s1[-1] and ispal(s1[1:])
```

Comment: You defined the function after you called it

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as pointed out by [TGKL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8004585/tgkl) you're calling `ispal` before it's defined. So define it before calling, i.e:

```
def ispal(s1):
    if len(s1) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        #if the first and last char are the same
        #and if all 
       return s1[0] == s1[-1] and ispal(s1[1:])

if s1.isalpha():
    if ispal(s1) == True:
        print(s,' is a palindrome')
    else:
        print(s,' is not a palindrome')
else:
    print('you entered illegal chars')
```

Second your palindrome recursive function is right except when you call `ispal` inside itself. Instead of `ispal(s1[1:])` you should do `ispal(s1[1:-1])` which will remove both the first and the last character, which has been just tested.

Comment: That's issss @Carlos Alfonso, you really really got this ;), +1, like it

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your method first, then call it:

```
s = raw_input('enter a string: ') #use raw_input so the text it takes will give to you directly a string without ""
s1 = s
s1 = s1.lower()
s1 = s1.replace(',', '')
s1 = s1.replace(' ', '')

def ispal(s1):
    if len(s1) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        #if the first and last char are the same
        #and if all 
       return s1[0] == s1[-1] and ispal(s1[2:]) # here you put ispal(s1[1:]) it doesn't work properly :/

if s1.isalpha():
    if ispal(s1) == True:
        print(s,' is a palindrome')
    else:
        print(s,' is not a palindrome')
else:
    print('you entered illegal chars')
```

Comment: One from the front and one from the back ;)

Comment: Exaaaaactly my pal @pepr, you really got this ;)

Comment: I'll have to take a closer look at this. I was actually getting the correct results - when it ran.

Comment: @femmebot I run it exactly as it is, exept for the part (s1[2:]) instead of (s1[1:]), and works fantastic! give it a try yourself and enjoy it :D

Comment: Added the last char notation [1: -1] as suggested below and seems to be working.

Comment: I'll take a look at that. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's not working for me. Are you trying it with a palindrome?

Comment: @femmebot I added a correction, now that is working with palindromes

Comment: @femmebot now it is perfect, with this you just only has to write the word you want, without ""

Comment: @femmebot good work! don't forget accept the answer if that helped you (with the (✓))